# Chosen multiselect does not show dropdown list on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

When all the select options are removed from mutli-select, it displays data-placeholder value, which is fine, but clicking select box for first time, it does not pull the drop down. On second click the multi-select works fine.

This problem happens in all browsers. I also have found the same problem in demos showed in below link.

Is there any fix for this issue?

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: I don't get that problem in the link...

Comment: Open the link
1) Goto multiselect section
2) Select one country to the multi select box
3) Remove the selected country by clicking close button inside select box
4) You can find dataplace holder value as "Choose a country"
5) On clicking "choose a country" does not pull drop down for first time, clicking again pulls the dropdown

Answer (score 2):

It might just be the functionality of it. After clearing out the option, they may want you to double click on it to clear out the text.

However if you want to report the bug I would suggest doing it on their github page.

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues

Comment: Fixed by adding:

this.active_field = false;
this.pending_destroy_click = false;
inside the the Chosen.prototype.choice_destroy method.

Comment: I would still let the authors know of the bug in their demo.